# Cargar datos de internet en RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, jsoup

*Buenas, una pregunta, ¿Cómo puedo cargar un `ArrayList` con datos de internet? Lo que quiero conseguir, es ingresar un texto en un `EditText` y que al presionar el `Button` se cargue un recyclerview con todos los datos de esa búsqueda.

He creado la siguiente **clase**:

```
    public class ParseItem {
    private String imgUrl;
    private String title;
    private String detailUrl;

    public ParseItem() {
    }

    public ParseItem(String imgUrl, String title, String detailUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        this.title = title;
        this.detailUrl = detailUrl;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDetailUrl() {
        return detailUrl;
    }

    public void setDetailUrl(String detailUrl) {
        this.detailUrl = detailUrl;
    }
}
```

Se la paso al **adaptador**:

```
    public class ParseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ParseAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ParseItem> parseItems;
    private Context context;

    public ParseAdapter(ArrayList<ParseItem> parseItems, Context context) {
        this.parseItems = parseItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ParseAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.parse_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ParseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ParseItem parseItem = parseItems.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(parseItem.getTitle());
        Picasso.get().load(parseItem.getImgUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return parseItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<ParseItem> newList) {
        parseItems = new ArrayList<>();
        parseItems.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Y esto es lo que hago en el **activity**:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buscar;
    EditText textoBusqueda;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ParseAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<ParseItem> parseItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new ParseAdapter(parseItems, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        textoBusqueda = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etBuscar);

        String texto = textoBusqueda.getText().toString();
        buscar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBusqueda);

        buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textoBusqueda.getText())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Debe ingresar el nombre del libro.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    textoBusqueda.setFocusable(true);
                }else{
                    Content content = new Content();
                    content.execute();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String url = "https://trantor.is/search/?q="+ textoBusqueda.getText().toString();
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.span1");
                int size = data.size();
                Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
                Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
                Log.d("size", ""+size);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    String imgUrl = data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("img")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("src");

                    String title = data.select("div.span7")
                            .select("span")
                            .eq(i)
                            .text();

                    String detailUrl = data.select("div.span7")
                            .select("a")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("href");

                    parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title, detailUrl));
                    Log.d("items", "img: " + imgUrl + " . title: " + title);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Adjunto el `layout`de la `activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/negro">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearBuscar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:hint="Buscar..."
                android:textColorHint="@color/blanco"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/etBuscar"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                android:id="@+id/btnBusqueda"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_search"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Y el `layout` del `adaptador`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        style="@style/CardView.Light"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="#88888888"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/gradient"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Pero, no me carga nada y en el logcat no muestra errores, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Actualmente en vez de `ListView` se usa `RecyclerView`. Y para traer datos remotos necesitarás alguna biblioteca como Volley o Retrofit para hacer la petición de red a la URL que sirve los datos a buscar. Esa respuesta la puedes mapear a objetos de la clase `Libros` fácilmente usando Gson. Si los datos están en Firebase ésta tiene su propia forma para mapear los datos a una clase. Sea como sea, la respuesta debería ser un array de objetos (Libros).

Comment: Pues, he modificado mi código y aún no funciona, ¿Me puedes decir como lograr lo que busco? @A.Cedano

Comment: Es que una eventual respuesta sería muy amplia. Hay varios asuntos para una posible solución: 1. Organizar la respuesta que vas a recibir del servidor como un `JSONArray`, donde estén todos los JSON con los datos de `Libros`; 2. Mapear esa respuesta para llenar un ArrayList de objetos de la clase `Libros`, 3. Llenar el `RecyclerView` con ese ArrayList. Es en tres pasos la solución que te propongo, pero en el código original, ni usas RecyclerView, ni usas Volley y parece que tienes una clase para mapear ¿? Si usarás GSon podrías mapear las respuestas de Volley directamente a objetos ...

Comment: ... de la clase `Libros` sin tener que escribir cadamvez otra clase para mapear datos de una respuesta a una clase del modelo. Por último,. Por convención de nombre, las clases generalmente debes escribirlas en singular `Libro`, no `Libros`, pues esto se presta a confusión y no te ayuda a entender tu programa.

Comment: Si te interesa el tipo de solución propuesta explora esa posibilidad y ante cualquier dificultad concreta te ayudaremos. El problema aquí es que para que funcione tienes que hacer muchos cambios en tu código. Entiendo es que es difícil enfrentarse con nuevas herramientas cuando ya parece que tienes todo. Pero es mejor perder un poco de tiempo en eso, luego lo ganarás en rendimiento de la Aplicación y aprenderás a manejar una herramienta que te ayudará a hacer con mayor facilidad tareas complicadas.

Comment: Es que he hecho algo de lo que mencionas. Modifiqué el código de la pregunta que hice para adaptarlo a lo que dices. uso un recyclerview, adapté el jsonarray y demases siguiendo un ejemplo en github pero el tratar de integrarlo a la página que yo quiero pues, no funciona @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no funciona? Usa Log cat para depurar el código, imprimiendo en cada etapa los datos con los que estés trabajando.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo " al presionar el Button se cargue un recyclerview con todos los datos de esa búsqueda.", te refieres a que al buscar una palabra traiga los datos que busca en Google y los agregue a tu Adapter ?

Comment: eso mismo solo que no es en Google sino en la **url** que puse en el método doinbackground() @Elenasys

Comment: podrías compartir la url y como se pide para ver que datos obtiene? @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: La url es: `https://trantor.is/` y cuando trae los datos es `https://trantor.is/search/?q=` **+ lo que hayas buscado**.  Por ejemplo si buscamos **el principito** la url quedará: `https://trantor.is/search/?q=el+principito` @Elenasys

Comment: Buenas tu error puede ser que necesites un handler  para la comunicacion de hilos de background a UIthread, el post execute y preexecute se ejecutan en que hilo background o el uithread?  Para actualizar cosas de interfaz de usuario se necesita el uithread. Tambien puede que el array en el hilo del background llegue como una nueva variable, entonces estas actualizando la vacia siempre, diferentes instancias. Utiliza un handler creado en el uithread puedes crearte en el oncreate y ya esta, manda mensaje para actualizar tu array y la ui.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo ok, entiendo lo que deseas realizar, veo que usas JSoup para obtener los datos del Html, y estos los deseas agregar al Adapter, permiteme revisar :-).

Comment: vale, gracias @Elenasys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al revisar tu código puedo ver dos problemas que impiden ver tus datos, el uso incorrecto del `AsyncTask` y el parseo usando [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Primeramente, con respecto a la obtención de datos, recuerda que el método `doInBackground()` debes usarlo para realizar el proceso de obtención de datos pero es importante especificar el valor de retorno (no uses null), el valor de retorno lo obtendrías en `onPostExecute()` y es aquí donde actualizarías los valores de tu Adapter.

Para actualizar te sugiero agregar el siguiente método en el Adapter que sería llamado en `onPostExecute()`

```
   public void updateData(ArrayList<ParseItem> items) {
        this.parseItems= items;
    }
```

y este sería el cambio en tu AsyncTask, obteniendo los datos en  `doInBackground()` y actualizando usando  `onPostExecute()`:

```
   private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ParseItem>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ParseItem> items) {
            super.onPostExecute(items);
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute() elementos obtenidos: " + items.size());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
            adapter.updateData(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ParseItem> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //Inicializa parseItems para evitar elementos repetidos.
            parseItems = new ArrayList<>();
            
            String url = "https://trantor.is/search/?q="+ textoBusqueda.getText().toString();
            
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.span1");
                int size = data.size();
                Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
                Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
                Log.d("size", ""+size);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    String imgUrl = data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("img")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("src");

                    String title = data.select("div.span7")
                            .select("span")
                            .eq(i)
                            .text();

                    String detailUrl = data.select("div.span7")
                            .select("a")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("href");

                    parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title, detailUrl));
                    
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return parseItems;
        }
    }
```

---

Ahora, un problema por el cual no visualizarías los datos es el parseo de los mismos dentro de la página web https://trantor.is/search/?q=el+principito , la forma correcta usando [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) se realizaría de la siguiente forma:

```
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ParseItem> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //Inicializa parseItems para evitar elementos repetidos.
            parseItems = new ArrayList<>();
            String url = "https://trantor.is/search/?q="+ textoBusqueda.getText().toString();
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground() url: " + url);
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements data = doc.select("div.span1");
                int size = data.size();
                Log.d("doc", "doc: "+doc);
                Log.d("data", "data: "+data);
                Log.d("size", ""+size);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                    String title = data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("img")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("alt");
                    String imgUrl = "https://trantor.is/" + data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("img")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("src");

                    String detailUrl = "https://trantor.is/" + data.select("div.span1")
                            .select("a")
                            .eq(i)
                            .attr("href");

                    parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title, detailUrl));
                    Log.i("items", " title: " + title +  " img: " + imgUrl) ;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground() Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return parseItems;
        }
```

---

Es importante tomar en cuenta que si usas un `ConstraintLayout` debes agregar restricciones a las vistas de otra forma tendràs problemas al desplegar los elementos en la vista. Es muy importante revisar:

[Cómo crear una IU responsiva con ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?hl=es-419)

Debes cuidar los colores, por ejemplo si tienes un fondo blanco y agregas un texto color blanco, este no se mostrarà en tu app.

Este es un layout `parse_item.xml` modificado el cual se mostrarìa correctamente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/CardView.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="224dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.294"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.188" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que al llenar los datos en tu Adapter se muestren de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa el ejemplo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-JSOAP

Comment: He quedado perplejo, funciona a la perfección pero me ha quedado una duda, el Array trae 22 cargas pero en la aplicación solo se ve uno, ¿Sabes por qué? Es decir, he realizado búsquedas comparando los rtesultados de la app con los del sitio web y en el sitio me trae 20 resultados, en el array de la app de trae 20 resultados pero en la app solo se muestra uno

Comment: ok, agregaste el método updateData() a tu Adapter como sugerí ?, si es así definitivamente deben mostrarse lo mismos resultados de la página en la app. Revisa si esta agregando a cada item el titulo y la ruta de la imagen.

Comment: Así es, he añadido ese método al adaptador pero solo veo un registro y ya probé buscando con otras palabras pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: pueden ser 2 las causas, que algunos objetos no tengan titulo y url o el Adapter tiene algún problema, que busqueda estas realizando?  Revisa si los items tienen titulo y url. Por cierto acabo de hacer el mismo proyecto lo puedo compartir en github. @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Pues, estoy buscando "el principito" para probar pero en la app solo me sale me sale un item. Si tú buscas "el principito", ¿Te salen más items en el recyclerview? Sería fantástico si me compartes el github

Comment: Hola Franqo me parece que el problema es el Constraintlayout , agregue algunos comentarios y el ejemplo, te sugiero revisar  https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?hl=es-419 es super importante para tus desarrollos, saludos!

Comment: Gracias genio, me ha servido de maravilla